# Please help me identify my bike model by this picture

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I got this bike more than 5 years ago and I don't remember its model. Every clue/reply to this post will help!

[image]

**Thanks!**

Comment: Some close-ups of the decals might help.

Comment: It looks a bit like the '[Atala Mitho](https://www.cercobici.com/item/atala-mitho-26-mtb-full-21v-disco-acciaio-2015/051299540812)', except for some details such as the breaks. Maybe a different year? Why do you want to know?

Comment: I'm fairly sure it's a "Winner Cheetah 18-speed MTB". And knowing the exact model isn't important because almost all parts except the frame itself are standard between brands.

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly low-end bike with 26 or perhaps 24 inch wheels.  The V brakes suggest that it is at least 5 years old and could be up to 20 years though I'd guess 10-15 based on the lack of boots on the front suspension stanchions.

The front shifter appears to be a thumb lever on a triple crankset, which also suggests a price-conscious design.  18/3 is 6 speed on the rear, which could be a cassette but is more likely to be a 14:28 freewheel.

There is very little space between the seat-tube and the rear triangle, so this bike could hit its own frame on any harder landing.  The rider must be a kid or very small adult to reduce this risk.

And it has a kickstand, a common sign of a kid's bike.  Nobody riding MTB would have something like that which could deploy on a landing and cause a problem.

---

It looks like a perfectly rideable bike, albeit for a smaller/younger person.  Absolutely fine for riding paths and trails, though probably not suitable for  anything aggressive or stunts or big drops.

Comment: The small space between the seat tube and rear triangle does not appear to be a point of contact on a hard landing as the rear triangle will move forward from that point of reference (the pivot is in the BB area), not up into the seat tube.